# PHP script to find all possible string combinations

Tags: php

I wrote a php script to find all combinations that fit a specific template.

Requirements are:

1) Find all combinations which use these characters:

"2", "3", "4", "6", "7", "8", "9", "Q", "W", "R", "T", "Y", "P", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "X", "C", "V", "B", "M"

2) Where each entry contains 25 characters in segments of 5, separated by a hyphen.

eg. XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX

3) Each segment cannot contain 5 of the same character

XXXXX-BBBBB... WRONG

XXXXB-BBBBM... GOOD

I wrote this script in PHP but it doesn't work well because it runs out of memory. I want to improve this script and maybe translate to another language.

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$input = array("2", "3", "4", "6", "7", "8", "9", "Q", "W", "R", "T", "Y", "P", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "X", "C", "V", "B", "M");
$length = 5;

function permut($input, $pos, $maxSame = null)
{
    $len = 1;
    $list = array();
    $listTemp = $input;
    foreach ($input as $fill) {
        while ($len < $pos) {
            $listNew = $listTemp;
            foreach ($input as $part) {
                foreach ($listNew as $p) {
                    $tmpNew = $p . $part;
                    $listTemp[] = $tmpNew;
                    if (strlen($tmpNew) == $pos) {
                        if ($maxSame == null)
                            $list[] = $tmpNew;
                        else {
                            $tmpSplit = str_split($tmpNew);
                            $tmpValues = array_count_values($tmpSplit);
                            $addToArray = true;
                            foreach ($tmpValues as $value) {
                                if ($value >= $maxSame) {
                                    $addToArray = false;
                                }
                            }

                            if ($addToArray)
                                $list[] = $tmpNew;
                        }

                        if (count($list) % 1000 == 0)
                            echo count($list) . "\n";
                    }
                }
            }
            $len++;
        }
    }
    //print_r($list);
}

permut($input, $length);
?>
```

Comment: Have you heard of regular expressions?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing all data in memory you can intermittently output data to a file so that the memory doesn't overflow

Comment: PHP save all combo's to file? I think all combination will be over ~200.000.000

Comment: Yes it will be a very large number of entries. You need to store it somewhere though. You have more room in hard drive storage than memory so you will have less problems. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: This is my homework. I wrote those script but i must improve that to A grade. I can create this combo finder in any language but it must be optimalised. My PHP script need to much hardware to generate .txt file with all combos. I think about MySQL and export all data as .txt file.

Comment: Whether you write to a db or to a file the idea is the same. Don't calculate everything at once. Do the work one chunk at a time to avoid overflowing.

Answer (score 0):

There are two obvious sub-problems that can be broken out here:

1. You want to find all non-repeating 5-character combinations of the given character set
2. You want to find all of the 5-string combinations of those strings.

First let's calculate how many combinations of #1 there are, given that there are 24 characters in your set:

```
24!/(5!*19!) - 24 = 42480
```

At 5 bytes each that will take up about 200KB of storage space, give or take. Not bad.

So how about #2 then?

```
42480!/(5!*42475!) = 1152495015245732528496 or 1.1*10^21
```

Cool. That's going to need ***28.81 trillion gigabytes***. Give or take.

On second thought, I don't think this is worth using most of the storage on earth.

edit: I originally screwed up the math pretty badly, but is fixed now.